# Validate array contains specific value using joi

Tags: javascript, joi

I'm looking for a way to validate that an array contains a required value using [joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi).
Found these issues online - [#1](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/554), [#2](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/pull/559), but none of them has a definitive answer.
I tried several stuff but they doesn't seem to work, like:
`joi.array().items(joi.string().allow('required-string').required())`,
`joi.array().items(joi.string().label('required-string').required())`,
`joi.array().items(joi.string().valid('required-string'))`

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

**Accepted:**

```
['required-string'], ['required-string', 'other'], ['other','required-string'], ['other',...,'required-string',....,'more-other']
```

**Denied:**

```
[], ['other'], [null], etc..
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array.items` by listing all allowed types. If a given type is `.required()` then there must be a matching item in the array:
[joi API reference](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.1.2/API.md#arrayitemstype)

```
joi.array().items(joi.string().valid('required-string').required(), joi.string())
```